# What is the use of bind() over call()? What extra we can do with bind() which we cant with call()?

Tags: javascript, call, bind, apply

What is the use of bind() over call()?
What extra bind() can do , which we can not do by using call()?

Comment: Can anybody explain the the exact difference in bind() and call() with examples?

Answer (score 1):

`call` executes a function (with an overridden `this` value and some arguments) **immediately**.

`bind` creates a new function which calls the old function (with an overridden `this` value and some *default* arguments). That new function can be called (as many times as desired) at some point **in the future**.

Comment: Can you please give me an example?